# pandas to calculate daily totals from cumulative multi-category columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df from which I have to calculate daily totals based on cumulative numbers. Here's a mockup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data  = {'col1': {0: '2020-02-25 20:00:00',
                                    1: '2020-02-25 22:00:00',
                                    2: '2020-02-26 20:00:00',
                                    3: '2020-02-26 23:00:00'},
                           'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'b'},
                           'col3': {0: 3, 1: 9, 2: 14, 3: 15}})
```

Outcome:
[image]

I know how to calculate daily totals from cumulative numbers:

```
df['dayTotal'] = df['col3'].diff().fillna(df['col3'])
```

But what I can't figure out is how to get the totals based on values in col2. I could `sort_values` but the cumulative dailies need to reset at each new value in col2. In the example there are only "a" and "b" values, but my real data has more than 500 categories.

The desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Use groupby `df.groupby('col2')['col3'].diff().fillna(df['col3'])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['dayTotal'] = df.sort_values('col1').groupby('col2')['col3'].diff().fillna(df['col3'])
df
```

Output:

```
                  col1 col2  col3  dayTotal
0  2020-02-25 20:00:00    a     3       3.0
1  2020-02-25 22:00:00    b     9       9.0
2  2020-02-26 20:00:00    a    14      11.0
3  2020-02-26 23:00:00    b    15       6.0
```

Comment: do you need `sort_values`?

Comment: Just to make sure the dates are in the correct order, what if the dates were totally inverted.  I am not relying on the present order but forcing a sort.  If you know your dataframe will be in order then yes, you can do away with the `sort_value`.

Comment: Scott, you're right. The dates are often totally out of order.